# How to change a status in sql correlating with time

Tags: sql, postgresql-8.4

Hi I am doing a project where I am stuck in the following the question asks me to make a booking entry for a travel agency using previous records such as bookingid, customerid, flightID number, passenger details etc and also the booking can have a status of reserved or held . If the seat is confirmed right away it is reserved and if not the passenger has 24 hrs to reserve and change it from held to reserve status. Also, if the seat isn't booked after 24 hrs it changes to expired status.

so far what I was able to come up with is

INSERT (values) INTO  the different tables and when it is booked right bookingid.status = R or bookingid.status = bookingtime > 24 = E

without a clue here so appreciate some help !!!

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways of doing this, but the easiest would be to initialize the booking status to **reserved** if it is booked right away and if it's not you would put **held**. Now, you would have to rely on a view (or another similar approach) to get the dynamically calculated status. If the user reserves his booking at a later time, you simply have to update the booking status to reserve.

*Note that I dont necessary suggest to represent statuses as strings, its just for the example.*

```
SELECT 
    CASE
        WHEN status = 'held' AND DATEDIFF(hh, booking_date, now()) > 24 THEN 'expired'
        ELSE status
    END AS status
FROM booking
```

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention this extra part before

Comment: Note that in a multi-user system, such as the CCA call centre, it is vital that control is maintained over the 
allocation of seats during the booking process. If, for example, customer A has requested the last two 
seats on a flight and is completing the booking process, it must not be possible for customer B to know 
that these seats are still available. Should customer A change his or her mind and abort the booking 
process, the seats will be made available again. Question 7, therefore, should provide a ‘safe’ booking 
based on the following typical call center transaction

Comment: on the following typical call center transaction
a. Check availability on a flight on a given date
b. Hold the requested seats until the booking is complete
c. Determine whether the customer already exists in the database; if not, create a new 
customer record
d. Confirm the details of all passengers, create new passenger records as required and 
complete the booking process.
e. Ensure that the correct number of seats and the correct total cost is showing for the booking.

Comment: on the following typical call center transaction
a. Check availability on a flight on a given date
b. Hold the requested seats until the booking is complete
c. Determine whether the customer already exists in the database; if not, create a new 
customer record
d. Confirm the details of all passengers, create new passenger records as required and 
complete the booking process.
e. Ensure that the correct number of seats and the correct total cost is showing for the booking.

Comment: Your booking procedure should be able to cope with the following situations:
- Before step (d), the number of seats can be changed
- Before step (d) the customer can change their mind and void the booking
- Until step (d) has taken place, ensure that the seats reserved in (b) cannot be allocated to 
another customer.

Comment: I'm sorry but I cannot make your homeworks for you =P However, you should now have a better idea on how to deal with dynamic statuses based on time. Good luck.